# php replace regular expression instead of string replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to give my client the ability to call a function that has various code snippets by inserted a short code in their WYSIWYG editor.

For example, they will write something like...

```
[getSnippet(1)]
```

This will call my getSnippet($id) php function and output the appropriate 'chunk'.

It works when I hard code the $id like this...

```
echo str_replace('[getSnippet(1)]',getSnippet(1),$rowPage['sidebar_details']);
```

However, I really want to make the '1' dynamic.  I'm sort of on the right track with something like...

```
function getSnippet($id) {
 if ($id == 1) {
  echo "car";
 }
}

$string = "This [getSnippet(1)] is a sentence.This is the next one.";
$regex = '#([getSnippet(\w)])#';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '. \1', $string);

//If you want to capture more than just periods, you can do:
echo preg_replace('#(\.|,|\?|!)(\w)#', '\1 \2', $string);
```

Not quite working :(

Comment: What does not work with your code?

Comment: Look at `preg_replace_callback()`. It lets you supply a function that receives the bits of the string that were matched by a regexp, and it returns the replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly in your regex you need to add literal parentheses (the ones you have just capture `\w` but that will not match the parentheses themselves):

```
$regex = '#(\[getSnippet\((\w)\)\])#';
```

I also escaped the square brackets, otherwise they will open a character class. Also be aware that this captures only one character for the parameter!

But I recommend you use `preg_replace_callback`, with a regex like this:

```
function getSnippet($id) {
    if ($id == 1) {
        return "car";
    }
}

function replaceCallback($matches) {
    return getSnippet($matches[1]);
}

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '#\[getSnippet\((\w+)\)\]#',
    'replaceCallback',
    $string
);
```

Note that I changed the `echo` in your `getSnippet` to a `return`.

Within the callback `$matches[1]` will contain the first captured group, which in this case is your parameter (which now allows for multiple characters). Of course, you could also adjust you `getSnippet` function to read the `id` from the `$matches` array instead of redirecting through the `replaceCallback`.

But this approach here is slightly more flexible, as it allows you to redirect to multiple functions. Just as an example, if you changed the regex to `#\[(getSnippet|otherFunction)\((\w+)\)\]#` then you could find two different functions, and `replaceCallback` could find out the name of the function in `$matches[1]` and call the function with the parameter `$matches[2]`. Like this:

```
function getSnippet($id) {
   ...
}

function otherFunction($parameter) {
   ...
}

function replaceCallback($matches) {
    return $matches[1]($matches[2]);
}

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '#\[(getSnippet|otherFunction)\((\w+)\)\]#',
    'replaceCallback',
    $string
);
```

It really depends on where you want to go with this. The important thing is, there is no way of processing an arbitrary parameter in a replacement without using `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response.  This seems really close at this point.  When I use a string such as ...

`$string = "[getSnippet(1)] this ijioj oiajs dfoij dsofij aoisfj oiasdfj. [getSnippet(2)] adfas asd as f. ";`
I'm just getting the text returned from the function but losing the other text...

`ie: Car. Boat.`

But it should be...

`"Car. this ijioj oiajs dfoij dsofij aoisfj oiasdfj. Boat. adfas asd as f. "`

Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much working the way I want except that the rest of the text in my sentence is being removed.  Only the text returned by the function calls is remaining.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please change that `echo` in `getSnippet` to a `return`. I thought I had changed that, but apparently I made some copy-paste mistake there.

Comment: @c.davies sorry that I rejected your edit, but I think an edit to an answer is not the right form of response in this case (since your changes were not apparent from the question in the first place). Of course, you can also return full HTML snippets in your callback functions, but that doesn't really change the solution to the problem (and makes it a bit too localized; i.e. less useful for future users with a similar problem). I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @c.davies No worries! I'm glad I could help. Welcome to SO! ;)

Comment: figured it out. No need for response.  I needed to echo $string at the very end of all this.